# Return substring at some byte length

Tags: javascript

If I have a string of say `" im wearing  today"` and wanted to say split the string at a certain byte length, ie `myString.slice(0, 4)` should give me back the wave emoji.

How would I go about doing that without going `new TextEncoder().encode(myString).subarray(0, 4)` — to decode again.

This is in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
const text = " im wearing  today"
const arr = text.split('')
const newArr = arr.slice(0, 4)
const result = newArr.join('')
```

Shorten:

```
const result = text.split('').slice(0, 4).join('')
```